# I created ionic4 rating bar but facing some errors

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, ratingbar

I have followed this link https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic4-rating. If I create rating bar in app.component page it works perfectly. But when I try to create rating bar in another page, like review page, I faced some problem:

1. If 'rating' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. To allow any element add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("

   [ERROR ->]
   "): ng:///PostreviewPageModule/PostreviewPage.html@11:2
   'rating' is not a known element:
3. If 'rating' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
4. To allow any element add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("

Answer (score 1):

**components.module.ts** which looks as follows:
add those

sourse [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA](http://To%20allow%20any%20element%20add%20'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA'%20to%20the%20'@NgModule.schemas'%20of%20this%20component.%20in%20Angular%204)

```
import { NgModule, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { SampleComponent } from './sample/sample';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [SampleComponent],
    imports: [],
    exports: [SampleComponent],
    schemas: [
        CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, // <-------
        NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA // <-------
      ]
})
export class ComponentsModule {}
```